# Duplicate Records on First run with dbt's Incremental Model on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

On one of the use case we have on our organisation, we have `incremental` tables which basically hold the append-only records of incoming events and `current` tables which stores the up-to-date state of incremental records with a unique key.

Above use-case looked us like an exact match to implement incremental model for good.

Documentation [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models) states that;

```
...the first time a model is run, the table is built by transforming all rows of source data.
```

Because we have more than one record with the same unique key on our append-only incremental tables, the first incremental run generates more than one record with same unique key on current tables. Hence, consecutive batch following error;

```
UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row
```

Could anyone please let me know how this issue can be addressed with a solution or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,
Soner

Comment: So are you using the incremental model type for just your "incremental" tables or your "current" tables as well?

Comment: Incremental tables have their incoming records apart from the dbt process. I am using dbt to generate only current tables out of incremental ones.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you are using it? You are using [BigQuery Profile](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-profiles/bigquery-profile) outside of GCP or you are using BigQuery on GCP? Did you see [Unique_key using multiple values?](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/unique-key-using-multiple-values/420) topic?

Comment: I am using BigQuery profile and BigQuery on GCP. Thank you for sharing the topic! Yes, I have seen it but it does address something else, having a unique key with multiple columns. This is not the case on my end. To elaborate, I am using dbt to transform raw data and create models out of them. So incremental tables (raw data) are BigQuery tables on GCP and there is a constant insertion into this tables. dbt stands to process incremental tables (raw data) and to generate the latest state of this records with a unique key and stores it in the model called current tables.

Comment: You have a multiple incremental tables which you want to incremental as one table using dbt? Lets say you have 3 tables and in each of them you have unique id like 1, 2 and 3 so it's considered by dbt as duplicate unique keys? Could you clarify what exactly you want to do, provide some scenario? Is this similar to [this thread](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/issues/2642)?

Comment: Using "unique key" word on incremental(inc) tables caused confusion. I have one-to-one relationship between inc and current tables. Inc tables can have multiple number of rows with the same value on their unique key column since it holds insert-only events. I have 3 tables, A_inc, B_inc and C_inc. I want 3 final tables, A_current, B_current and C_current which stores the latest incoming record with unique key on *_current tables. Current tables can not have duplicate records with the same unique key. I use dbt's incremental model and it duplicates the records on current table in the first run.

Comment: Hi @SonerGuzeloglu . So lets say we take A_inc & A_current as an example. You want to pick the latest data for each unique key from A_inc, right? So my question is how do you define the latest record. If we have two rows in A_inc with same Unique Key, which one of this will be considered as latest? Any date column or what? If you could answer this, I can provide you with the solution. PS Do add up table structure & model code for better elaboration of question

Answer (score 1):

If your case is that you only need to keep the latest version of the same ID, you could first remove the duplicates by using a window function in a CTE.

In my case, I am using BigQuery and I had exact duplicates and less updated data of the same ID. Here's how I handled it.

For the header, I materialized as incremental, and select id as unique_key.

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='id'
    )
}}
```

you query the relevant columns as usual. I put the is_incremental inside this CTE.

```
with cte as ( ... {% if is_incremental() %} ... ),
```

now to handle the duplicates

```
no_dupe as (
    select 
        distinct *, -- this is to handle the exact duplicate
        row_number() over(partition by id order by datemodified desc) as rank_uptodate -- this is to rank the row with the latest modified one as 1.
    from cte
),

no_dupe_final as (
    select * except(rank_uptodate) 
    from no_dupe
    where rank_uptodate = 1 -- this is where you only fetch the most up to date version of the same id
)

select * from no_dupe_final
```

this will work both for full-refresh and for incrementals.
Change id and datemodified to the relevant columns in your case.